# Shared preferences in Android doesn't save when i switch activity or close app

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I checked similar questionsions and noting seems to work. I can't figure out what seems to be the problem. Value goes to 0 after every app restart or activity switch.

```
//just parts of code from activity1
            SharedPreferences pref;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
// On create....
            pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            editor = pref.edit();
            max=pref.getInt("mxtime", 0);

//If something>something...
            editor.putInt("mxtime", max);
            editor.commit();
```

In the first part i declare SharedPreferences in main Activity. I save it in "max" int and its always 0 on startup since if empty value is 0. On second activity I have a button, where on click it should empty the value from SharedPreferences.

Activity 2:

```
public class settings extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button myButton;
private Button myButton2;
private Button myButton3;
//sharedPrefs
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = pref.edit();
    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    myButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });
    myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //sharedPrefs
            editor.remove("mxtime");
            editor.commit();


        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: **Why** do you remove the preference from your preferences `editor.remove("mxtime");`? And **where** do you set a value for `max`?

Comment: I set value for max just before saving it in SharedPrefs. And i changed editor.remove to editor.clear().

Comment: **Why** do you remove all the preferences from your preferences `editor.clear();`? And **which** is the value you assign to `max`?

Comment: Because that button is to reset all values from preferences. But even if i don't go to second activity and click it won't save the value.

Comment: Can you show **how** do you assign a value to `max`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, found out what was wrong now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use SharedPreferences like this:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

Comment: This worked when i tryed it, then i tryed it for second time and it went to 0 again. I can't figure out what is going wrong

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy `editor.apply()` is only faster (because it's asynchronous).

Comment: and it's saver than use commit() because it run in background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Activity 1:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("YourSharedPreference", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
int DEFAULT_VALUE = 0;
editor.putInt("VARIABLE_KEY", DEFAULT_VALUE);

//If something > something..

int VALUE_TO_PASS = <your value here>;
editor.putInt("VARIABLE_KEY", VALUE_TO_PASS);

// Before screen shift

editor.commit();
```

...........................................

Activity 2:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("YourSharedPreference", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int DEFAULT_FALLBACK_VALUE = 0;  //When value is not received, show this

int VALUE_PASSED = sp.getInt("VARIABLE_KEY", DEFAULT_FALLBACK_VALUE);

// On button click:

int DEFAULT_VALUE = 0;
editor.putInt("VARIABLE_KEY", DEFAULT_VALUE);
editor.commit();
```