# Android: Display High Score on Main Menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPerefences to save my high score and it works to display on the death menu(I use Intent with it too), however I wanted to display the high score on the main menu, but it is not working out how can I get the high score displaying on the main menu.

**Game Activity (saving the high score)**

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = msharedPreferences.edit();
 editor.putInt("bestScore",iBestScore);
 editor.commit();
```

**Main Activity (getting the high score)**

```
final SharedPreferences msharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPredences(getBaseContext());
int bestScore = msharedPreferences.getInt("bestScore",0);
```

Comment: thanks @Enzokie, that type is not in code only in the post.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "it's not working out"? Is there no score? Are you getting an exception? Please explain further

Comment: @Chisko It runs fine, however it is also at the default number 0

Comment: Where have you put the code to get the shared preference in `MainActivity`...it should ideally be in `onPause()`

Comment: @Shaishav I placed it, inside of onCreate() I will place it inside onPause() and give you an update.

Comment: HALT!...my bad..I meant `onResume()` NOT `onPause()`...

Comment: @Shaishav I wrote this  and the app crashes. Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Get best score
        final SharedPreferences msharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        int bestScore = msharedPreferences.getInt("bestScore", 0);
        bestLabel.setText("Best Score: " + bestScore);

    }

Comment: What line does it crashes on? What does the error says?

Comment: @Shaishav nevermind it was a different line of code I messed up, however the high score is still showing up as 0 even though it is 23.

Comment: You need to describe your app flow a bit: eg - user opens mainactivity, goes to game activity, plays, i save the score after button click and then come back to mainactivity...etc...something like that

Comment: @Shaishav alright so the user opens up the app and is presented with the main menu (when the app loads up and the viewer is on the main menu I want the high score to be displayed), then they hit the play button, play till they die and are presented with the death screen where the final score is presented and they are given an option to replay the game.

Comment: You should avoid using `getBaseContext()`...use the method mentioned by @DsD

Comment: @Shaishav I took your advice and tried it out and it worked well, thank you very much for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: Cool...happy coding..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your **saving and reading shared preference is SAME**.

It is better to access shared preference using custom name.

Saving in SP:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("YourSharedPreference", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
```

Reading from SP:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("YourSharedPreference", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int VALUE_PASSED = sp.getInt("VARIABLE_KEY", DEFAULT_FALLBACK_VALUE);
```

The complete code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36542924/5089018)

Comment: Great that helped you :)!!